# How to run one Jenkins job periodically until the the other Jenkins job is running

Tags: jenkins

I have two Jenkins jobs - JobA and JobB. I will trigger JobA. Now I want to run the JobB periodically every 5 minutes until JobA is running. So if JobA runs for say 30 mins, jobB will get triggered after each 5 mins and in total it will run for 6 times. Kindly help if this can be achieved in Jenkins.

Thanks,
Sourabh

Comment: Not sure I understand your scenario, but maybe install [build-blocker-plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-blocker-plugin/), set jobB to run on a schedule, 5 min interval (H/5), set to block if JobA is running. JobB will ALWAYS run every 5 min, unless JobA is running. Correct interpretation?

Comment: is it freestyle job ?

Comment: @PDHide yes it is a freestyle job

Comment: @lan W JobB should run every 5 mins as long as  job A is running

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to keep jobB running every 5 mins till jobA is completed.

You can create an upstream job, jobC which will poll/check status of jobA and if it is running, will trigger jobB. If jobA is not running, jobC should fail, not triggering jobB.

You can schedule jobC to be triggered on every 5 mins.

OR,

You can just trigger jobB and first validate the status of jobA. If jobA is not running, fail jobB else complete the execution.

Comment: Could you please explain me how can I achieve either of this. Basically I want to know how can i poll or validate the status of JobA